# How to show a new column after using select2 in laravel?

Tags: laravel

I have a form and using select2 for filter. I want to show new column by using this select2. 
I don't know its possible or not but i want to do this . using jquery or something, can someone reference to me about this? its my form for my input

```
 <form class="form-prevent-multiple-submits" data-toggle="validator" action="{{route('update_sarpras_aduan'),'test'}} " method="post">
                  @csrf
                  {{method_field('patch')}}
                <div class="form-group">
                <label class="control-label" for="title">Nama Unit:</label>
                    <input type="text" name="nama_unit" id="nama_unit" class="form-control" data-error="Please enter title." required disabled/>
                    <div class="help-block with-errors"></div>
                  </div>
                <div class="form-group">
                    <label class="control-label" for="title">Tanggal Aduan:</label>
                    <textarea name="created_at" class="form-control" id="tgl_aduan" data-error="Please enter description." readonly ></textarea>
                    <div class="help-block with-errors"></div>
                  </div>
                <div class="form-group">
                      <label class="control-label" for="title">Nama Pengadu:</label>
                      <input type="text" name="nama_pengadu" class="form-control" id="nama_pengadu" data-error="Please enter title." readonly />
                      <div class="help-block with-errors"></div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="form-group">
                        <label> Isi Aduan </label>
                        <textarea name="aduan" id="aduan" class="form-control" rows="3" placeholder="Isi Aduan atau Keluhan ..."  readonly ></textarea>
                      </div>


                    <div class="form-group">
                      <label class="control-label" for="title">Nama Teknisi:</label>
                      <input type="text" name="nama_teknisi" class="form-control" id="nama_teknisi" data-error="Please enter title."  readonly />
                      <div class="help-block with-errors"></div>
                    </div>
              ----------------here this select2---------------------------
                    <div class="form-group">
                      <label>Pilih Inventaris</label>
                      <select class="form-control select2bs4" name="alat_id" id="alat_id" style="width: 100%;" aria-hidden="true">
                        @foreach($inven as $id => $item )
                        <option value="{{ $id }}">{{ $item }} </option>
                        @endforeach
                      </select>
                    </div>




             --------------------------------------------------
                     <div class="form-group">
                      <label>Status Saat Ini  (Jangan Lupa Diganti)</label>  
                      <select name="status" id="status" class="form-control">  

                           <option value="Tindakan Lanjutan">Tindakan Lanjutan</option>
                           <option value="Selesai">Selesai</option>  
                      </select>  
                      <div class="help-block with-errors"></div>
                    </div>


                    <div class="form-group">
                      <label> Tindakan Pelaksana </label>
                      <textarea name="tindakan" id="tindakan" class="form-control" rows="3" placeholder="Isi Tindakan Yang dilakukan"  required ></textarea>
                    </div>

                     <div class="form-group">
                          <label>Kondisi Alat </label>  
                          <select name="status_alat" id="status_alat" class="form-control">  
                               <option value="Baik">Baik</option>  
                               <option value="Rusak Ringan">Rusak Ringan</option>
                               <option value="Rusak Berat">Rusak Berat</option>

                          </select>  
                          <div class="help-block with-errors"></div>
                        </div>








                  <input type="hidden" name="id" id="id" value="">
                  <input type="hidden" name="user_id" id="user_id" value="">
                  <input type="hidden" name="ipsrs_id" id="ipsrs_id" value="">
                  <input type="hidden" name="teknisi_id" id="teknisi_id" value="">

                  <input type="hidden" name="ended_at" id="ended_at" value="">
                  <div class="form-group">
                    <button type="button" class="btn btn-danger" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
                    <button type="submit" id="button" class="btn btn-success crud-submit-edit button-prevent-multiple-submits">
                        <i class="spinner fa fa-spinner fa-spin" ></i>
                      Submit</button>
                  </div>
                    </form>
```

after using this select2 , will showing a new form . can someone references to me about this ?

Comment: if i quite understand you. do you want the new form to display when you select select2?

Comment: Yes , this is my point

Comment: see sample code snippet below

Answer (score 1, accepted):

//select input

```
<div class="form-group">
      <label>Pilih Inventaris</label>
      <select class="form-control select2bs4" name="alat_id" id="alat_id" style="width: 100%;" aria-hidden="true" onchange="Show()">
      @foreach($inven as $id => $item )
      <option value="{{ $id }}">{{ $item }} </option>
      @endforeach
      </select>
   </div>
```

//new form

```
<div id="divid" style="display:none">
 <form method="" action="">
  @csrf

 </form
<div>
```

//javascript code

```
<script>
 function Show()
  {
     var fieldValue =  $('#alat_id').val();


        if(fieldValue == "")
         {
          document.getElementById("divid").style.display = 'none';
           }
        else{
          document.getElementById("divid").style.display = 'inline'
          }           
     }

</script>
```

Comment: Wait , i'll try

Comment: hello sir  i want to ask something

Comment: I will ask in different question i think . Its solved for this